# Update Button state onClick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two buttons on a page and based on a state in that component, a particular button should be displayed, I have tried for hours, still not working

Here is my code

```
const App = () =>{
    const [edit,setEdit] = useState(false)
    
    
    const updateUser =() =>{
        //update action
        setEdit(false)
    }
    
    return(
        <div> 
            <form>
                <input type="text"/>
                <input type="text"/>
                {edit ? (<button onClick={()=>updateUser()}>Save</button>) : (<button onClick={()=>{setEdit(true)}}>Edit</button>)}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default App;
```

when the page loads the button shows Edit, but after clicking, i expect it to change to save since `edit` is now true, but it still remains same

Comment: In the `useEffect` you always set `icon` to save and in the button's `onClick` there is a `setEditmode` function, which doesn't exist.

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: Any reason `useEffect` and `updateUser` is outside of the component?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Great, now you just need to use `App` instead of `app` as component name should be uppercase and it will work :) (Probably would add `<form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>` to prevent page reload.)

Comment: The question has been updated

Answer (score 1):

you have a side effect in this situation caused by `edit` so you should make use of good old pal useEffect also those prevenDefaults will prevent your form from refreshing and are necessary. I made a livedemo at [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-water-o8ehp?file=/src/App.js:0-736) and here is the code itself:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const App = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

  const updateUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //update action
    setEdit(false);
  };

  const editUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //stuffs you wanna do for editing
    setEdit(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, [edit]);
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => updateUser(e)}>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        {edit ? (
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={(e) => editUser(e)}>Edit</button>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

P.S: Although it works, I don't approve of the approach

Answer (score 0):

Not need to using `useEffect` just check if edit is true or not !

**EDIT** : I made it this way so u can see what happend and i think u should learn more about react and hooks , i prefer watching youtube!

```js
const App = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(true);
  
  const clickHandler =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!edit){
      // update user information here not need to make
      // different function and state or somthing else.
      console.log("updateUser")
    }
    setEdit(prev=>!prev);
  }
  
  return(
        <div> 
            <form>
                <input type="text"/>
                <input type="text"/>
                <button onClick={clickHandler} disabled={!edit}>Edit</button> 
                <button onClick={clickHandler} disabled={edit}>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for this,  please i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach also, Here I used `e.preventDefault` on the event when submitting the form to prevent a browser reload/refresh.

```
const App = () =>{
const [edit,setEdit] = useState(false)


const updateUser =(e) =>{
    //update action
    e.preventDefault();
    setEdit(!edit);
}
    return(
        <div> 
            <form>
                <input type="text"/>
                <input type="text"/>
                {edit ? (<button onClick={updateUser}>Save</button>) : 
                (<button onClick={updateUser}>Edit</button>)}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: The browser does not load, It is not refreshing, so the problem is not preventing form submission

Comment: But, it is the default behavior of the forms so we have to control reloading. You can read more about controlled components at https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

As I see it, your issue is that the buttons don't have a `type` specified to them, so they *actually* inherit an initial value of `type="submit"` and this causes your `form` to take the default submit action and reload the page. You likely aren't seeing this reload as it may be occurring very quickly.

[type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

> The default behavior of the button. Possible values are:
>
> - `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated
>   with a `<form>`, or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value.**
> - `reset`: The button resets all the controls to their initial values, like `<input type="reset">`. (This behavior tends to annoy users.)
> - `button`: The button has no default behavior, and does nothing when pressed by default. It can have client-side scripts listen to the
>   element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

## Solution

Provide/specify the button types to *not* be "submit and valid, i.e. use `type="button"`.

```
const App = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(false);

  const updateUser = () => {
    //update action
    setEdit(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        {edit ? (
          <button type="button" onClick={updateUser}>
            Save
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setEdit(true);
            }}
          >
            Edit
          </button>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is an example that also, IMO, make the code a bit more DRY.

```
const App = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(false);

  const updateUser = () => {
    //update action
    setEdit(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            edit ? updateUser() : setEdit(true);
          }}
        >
          {edit ? "Save" : "Edit"}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit update-button-state-onclick-react]